# Iterative querying the ArangoDB using AQL

Tags: key-value, arangodb, aql

I have stored the JSON data in ArangoDB collection in the following format.

```
{ 
  "data": {
    "1":   [ {"db_name": "DSP"}, {"rel": "2"} ], 
    "2":   [ {"rel_name": "DataSource"}, {"tuple": "201"}, {"tuple": "202"}, {"tuple": "203"} ],
    "201": [ {"src_id": "Pos201510070"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151007"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "postgres"}, {"port": "None"} ],
    "202": [ {"src_id": "pos201510060"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"},{"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151006"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "DSP"}, {"port": "5432"} ],
    "203": [ {"src_id": "pos201510060"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151006"}, {"user_name": "postgres"},{"src_type": "Structured"},{"db_name": "maindb"},{"port": "5432"} ]
  }
}
```

I am new to ArangoDB. I have no idea about the storing and querying the data from ArangoDB. In my data there is no any predefined key, and the data get populated with time. My data is just like a semi-structured data which do not have any fixed number of attributes, and little bit complex due to its iterative list structure.

First, anyone can suggest me the best way for storing the above format in ArangoDB.

Second, I want to query this data in following manner: by specifying any key (not known in advance, by specifying it at runtime), or by specify combinations of key and value pair, e.g., `Key1 == value1`, or the combination using AND or OR logical operators like `Key1 == value1 AND Key2 == value2 OR Key3== value3`.

So, how we can iterate over the above data?

Comment: I have tried the query "For u in Collecton_name return u" It is just like the querying a relational data using select * from table_name;

Comment: It's a bit unclear what kind of query result is actually desired. For example, to iterate over all attributes in each document, you can use nested FOR loops in AQL as follows: `FOR doc IN collection LET attributes = ATTRIBUTES(doc.data) FOR attribute IN attributes RETURN { key: attribute, value: doc.data[attribute] }`

Comment: I want to access only those where db_name == "main_db" or i want the list  the values corresponding to the attribute name like src_type etc..

Comment: Thanks, I also want to know that whether we can formulate the query like above on run tike as the number of conditions gets increased.

Comment: Can you explain why your data structure uses an array of objects, with only a single attribute each? Looks like your data model is not well defined. To understand your problem better, it might help if you post the equivalent SQL query you would use to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to store data in a structure like this, without any predefined attribute names, you can still iterate over the data by converting it into a normalized structure on-the-fly.

The following AQL query creates a flat list of key/value pairs for each document:

```
FOR doc IN collection 
  LET attributes = ATTRIBUTES(doc.data) 
  FOR attribute IN attributes 
    FOR arrayItem IN doc.data[attribute] 
      LET key = ATTRIBUTES(arrayItem)[0] 
      LET value = arrayItem[key] 
      RETURN { _key: doc._key key: key, value: value }
```

The result of this query will be something like this:

```
[ 
  { 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "password", 
    "value" : "root" 
  }, 
  { 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "db_name", 
    "value" : "postgres" 
  }, 
  { 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "port", 
    "value" : "None" 
  }, 
  ...
]
```

Now you can apply the filtering easily by adding the filter conditions of choice:

```
FOR doc IN collection 
  LET attributes = ATTRIBUTES(doc.data) 
  FOR attribute IN attributes 
    FOR arrayItem IN doc.data[attribute] 
      LET key = ATTRIBUTES(arrayItem)[0] 
      LET value = arrayItem[key] 
      FILTER key == 'password' || key == 'port' || (key == 'db_name' && value == 'postgres') 
      RETURN { _key: doc._key, key: key, value: value }
```

Note that when the data structure changes (more/less levels of nesting), the above won't work anymore. The query assumes documents with a structure as presented in the question.

Comment: Thanx stj...., Can you please guide me how i can remove the restriction regarding the more/less levels of nesting....

Comment: Is there any way to remove this restriction??

Comment: and can you suggest me some good tutorial for me as the beginner of ArangoDB??

Comment: The structure is hard-coded in the query I wrote. There is a `FOR` loop for each level of nesting. I don't think there is a way to process arbitrarily-structured documents in AQL without knowing anything about the structure. This will also be difficult with other languages I think. What I therefore suggest is to define at least a minimal structure and use this for all documents.

Comment: Re tutorials: the official documentation is at https://docs.arangodb.com/ and there's also a list of cookbook recipes here: https://docs.arangodb.com/cookbook/

Comment: Thanks stj....Please Tell me one more thing, If all data is internally converted into the above shown structure, as {{ 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "password", 
    "value" : "root" 
  }, 
  { 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "db_name", 
    "value" : "postgres" 
  }, 
  { 
    "_key" : "864582648369", 
    "key" : "port", 
    "value" : "None" 
  },..}

Comment: then is it better to convert our data explicitly in above structure, n then stored into ArangoDB instead of the structured stored in my collection which i have given previously??

Comment: You could store objects such as `{ "_key" : "864582648369", "key" : "password", "value" : "root" }` as individual documents in a collection. Then querying & filtering becomes easy. However, if several of these objects logically belong together (apparently they do because they were grouped by some keys in the original data), then you may want to store the group's key in the document too, e.g. `{ "_key" : "864582648369", "key" : "password", "value" : "root", "group" : "101" }`. But if that's reasonable depends on the purpose of the data and what kind of queries you intend to run on them.

Comment: In the above json data, i want to retrieve the documents only the specific key-value pair, suppose i want to retrieve the document where db_name is postgres, so i have make the filter condition as given above (key == 'db_name' && value == 'postgres') , But this query is returning the empty set. If I use || then returns the extra document. Kindly tell me if any other suitable option is available for the above query. i have use the format { "_key" : "864582648369", "key" : "password", "value" : "root", "group" : "101" } to store the json object.

Comment: Just tried with the above example data, and adding the condition `FILTER key == 'db_name' && value == 'postgres'` returns `{ "_key" : "18640413109", "key" : "db_name", "value" : "postgres" }` just fine. `&&` of course will not work if key == `db_name` and value == `postgres` are contained in different sub-parts, but in the example data it should just work fine. If not, please can you show the data and query you're using? Thanks.

Comment: Hello stj, thank for helping me. Please tell me one thing if i am using the nested key-value as shown in the posted question, n if i am iterating the collection, then how can i determine the value of main keys in the above document structure..

Comment: For example, { 
 "data": {
    "1":   [ {"db_name": "DSP"}, {"rel": "2"} ], 
    "2":   [ {"rel_name": "DataSource"}, {"tuple": "201"}, {"tuple": "202"}, {"tuple": "203"} ],
    "201": [ {"src_id": "Pos201510070"}, {"src_name": "Postgres"}, {"password": "root"}, {"host": "localhost"}, {"created_date": "20151007"}, {"user_name": "postgres"}, {"src_type": "Structured"}, {"db_name": "postgres"}, {"port": "None"} ],
  
  }
} How can i retrieve the keys "1", "2", "201" etc in this document..

Comment: Hello stj, Kindly tell me the answer of the above question, How we can determine the value of keys as "1", "2", "201" etc